# How to force links inside a fixed positioned div to display when they are out of screen viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a fixed sidebar inside a div which has a lot of navigation links. The work is done in pure CSS so far. Everything works fine except one issue. The problem is when user goes to a link which is outside of desktop computer's screen viewport then due to fixed position of parent div the link doesn't appear in the visible region and we can't see on what links we are currently. How to force the links to display in visible part of the screen when a bottom link is clicked?

Remember, I am working with standard page load and NO ajax for links load.

```css
#left_sidebar {
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
 border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    bottom:0;
    width:200px;
 padding-top:15px;
}

#left_sidebar h4 {
 margin-left:15px;
}

#left_sidebar ul li a {
 color:#333333;
 display:block;
 padding:5px 5px 5px 15px;
 font-size:14px;
}

#left_sidebar ul li a.active,
#left_sidebar ul li a:hover {
 background-color:#DDDDDD;
 color:#000000;
}

.mousescroll {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.mousescroll:hover {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
    <div id="left_sidebar" class="mousescroll">
        <ul>
            <h4>Links</h4>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Link</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

Comment: The code example you posted in your question does not adequately demonstrate the problem you are reporting, so gives nothing to play with. Please improve your example/demo to clearly demonstrate the problem. (In doing so, you are likely to solve the problem yourself - but if you cannot, then one of us would be happy to assist once we understand the problem).

Comment: Please provide code which replicates the problem

Comment: Please see w3schools sidebar navigation how the bottom links always appear in viewport area when clicked.